# Flask-Assets and Flask-Testing throws RegisterError: Another bundle is already registered

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, webassets

I have my Flask app which uses Flask-Assets and while trying to run the unittest cases, except the first testcase, others fails with the following RegisterError.

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_login_page (tests.test_auth.AuthTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cnu/env/flenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 133, in run
    self.runTest(result)
  File "/Users/cnu/env/flenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 151, in runTest
    test(result)
  File "/Users/cnu/env/flenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_testing.py", line 72, in __call__
    self._pre_setup()
  File "/Users/cnu/env/flenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_testing.py", line 80, in _pre_setup
    self.app = self.create_app()
  File "/Users/cnu/Projects/Bookworm/App/tests/test_auth.py", line 8, in create_app
    return create_app('testing.cfg')
  File "/Users/cnu/Projects/Bookworm/App/bookworm/__init__.py", line 118, in create_app
    configure_extensions(app)
  File "/Users/cnu/Projects/Bookworm/App/bookworm/__init__.py", line 106, in configure_extensions
    assets.register('js_all', js)
  File "/Users/cnu/env/flenv/src/webassets/src/webassets/env.py", line 374, in register
    'as "%s": %s' % (name, self._named_bundles[name]))
RegisterError: Another bundle is already registered as "js_all": <Bundle output=assets/packed.js, filters=[<webassets.filter.jsmin.JSMin object at 0x10fa8af90>], contents=('js/app.js',)>
```

My understanding of why this happens in before the first testcase is run, create_app creates an instance of app and this is maintained for all other testcases.

I tried `del(app)` in the teardown method, but doesn't help.

Is there some way to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

You probably have a global object for the assets environment, which you have declared as such :

in file `app/extensions.py`:

```
from flask.ext.assets import Environment
assets = Environment()
```

Then, somewhere in your `create_app` method, you should init the environment:

in file `app/__init__.py`:

```
from .extensions import assets

def create_app(): 
    app = Flask(__name__)
    ...
    assets.init_app(app)
    ...
    return app
```

The thing is that when you initialize your environment with you app, the registered bundles aren't cleared. So you you should do it manually as such in your TestCase:

in file `tests/__init__.py`

```
from app import create_app
from app.extensions import assets

class TestCase(Base): 

    def create_app(self): 
        assets._named_bundles = {} # Clear the bundle list
        return create_app(self)
```

Hope this helps, 
Cheers